# how to create and update an observable, which depends on an @Input

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

A simple component has an input (i.e. `criteria`) and an observable (i.e. `result$`).

```
class Foo {
  @Input()
  private criteria: string;

  private result$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private service: MyService) { }
}
```

The class MyService, provides a method, which consumes the `criteria` and returns the observable which should be used to set/update `result$`.

```
service.fetchResult(criteria: string): Observable<any>
```

What is the state-of-the-art way to create the observable, by using this service.
The most important requirement being:

- also when the input (i.e. `criteria`) is modified later, the new  value should be used to update the observable (i.e. `result$`).

Comment: You can use ngOnChnage hook to listen for the input changes and updated the observable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `set`:

```
_criteria: Criteria; // set local variable if this input needed elswhere
@Input()
set criteria(c: Criteria) {
  this.service.someMethod(c);
  this._criteria = c;
}
```

With `OnChanges`:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  let criteria = changes.criteria;
  if(criteria && criteria.currentValue !== criteria.previousValue){
    this.service.someMethod(criteria);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just one additional question. - I am a bit puzzled why you put the refresh of the service in `ngOnChanges` while you could also put it in the `set criteria`. Am I correct that you are doing this with the mindset that this solution would also work when there are multiple required inputs for the service ?

Comment: These snippets belongs in the component class and are two ways you could get notified when `Input()` changes. `NgOnChanges()` feels as a cleaner solution if you have several inputs and need to be notified when they change

Comment: Actually, what is somehow missing from this answer, is how `result$` is updated. I am wondering if it can just be `result$ = this.service.fetchResult(criteria)` ? It seems somewhat wasteful that a new observable needs to be created with each update. Shouldn't it be like the same observable can be reused but kind of channels news values ?

Comment: If we talk about the **cold** Observable, so it's just a function - it completes and is is done. If it's **hot**, you should be aware of memory leaks